# Issue with datetime in mysql where clause

Tags: mysql

Hi all I think this is a lame question, but I can't figure out why? I have a table with three rows like below.

[image]

I'm querying it with below code. But the result always contain all the three rows! It should be the rows with id 3 and 4 right?

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `hs_room_slots_tbl` 
WHERE  'from' >=  '2016-12-07 10:00:00'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

'from' field is a datetime field. I'm querying this in phpmyadmin query box. What might be the problem?

Comment: `SELECT * 
FROM  \`hs_room_slots_tbl\` 
WHERE  from >=  '2016-12-07 10:00:00'` (**You don't put quotes around column names, because otherwise it will be treated as a *string***)

Comment: There is a major difference between ``` and `'`...

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie Yeah, the single quotes was the problem, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean to escape your `from` column using backtique and not quoting it using single quote as below. Else, it will be treated as string literal instead of column name

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `hs_room_slots_tbl` 
WHERE  `from` >=  '2016-12-07 10:00:00'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM  `hs_room_slots_tbl` WHERE  `from` >= '2016-12-07 10:00:00'
```

**You don't put quotes around column names, because otherwise it will be treated as a *string***

In this case you have to use `from` because "from" is a **mysql keyword**.

Comment: Yes, the backtique did the job :)